# how to make magit log search case-insensitive

Tags: magit, case-folding

How would I make magit log searches case insensitive.. I see references in emacs to `transient:magit-log-refresh:--regexp-ignore-case` but not sure how to turn it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From git status press `l` a single time. Then press `C-x a` to [show all suffix levels](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Enabling-and-Disabling-Suffixes.html). You will find the option under `-i`. I guess you can/should combine it with your preferred search option.

Comment: Also `C-x C-s` to save the currently-selected transient options persistently.

Comment: Awesome. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those coming in to view the answer, here is a screenshot showing the expanded options. [image]